# Unable to connect to Realm Object Server in browser ( AWS EC2 instance)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, realm-mobile-platform

I've scoured the web for two days and have not found a solution. Thanks in advance for the help!

I am following [this](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/installation/linux/) tutorial to set up a realm object server on AWS, and I launched an instance of this hvm: ami-fd81f8eb. I **can ssh into my ec2 instance**, but I **can't connect to the server’s public DNS in my web browser** (tried safari and chrome).

I opened up every port in my security group that I thought may be relevant (and yes, I confirmed that this security group is selected for my ec2 instance).

- HTTP port 80 allowed on all IP's
- HTTPS port 22 allowed on all IP's
- Custom TCP Rule port 9080 allowed on all IP's
- SSH allowed on all ports on all IP's
- And I also opened "All Traffic" to all IP's

I have also noticed that commands such as `sudo service realm-object-server status` result in `● realm-object-server.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

This is leading me to believe that there is an issue with the AMI, which would be impossibly unlikely, but I can't find any file related to the realm object server in my instance. Here is what my directory looks like as I try to navigate to var/log/realm-object-server.log

[Navigating Through Server Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ai0cp.jpg)

Any ideas?? What am I overlooking? Thanks!

Comment: It seems unlikely that their official AMI would be broken.  AMIs are frozen when created, so it isn't possible to create one that works and inadvertently (or intentionally) break it, later, with a change, since AMIs can't be changed.  Have you looked at `/var/log/realm-object-server.log` (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/74))?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I saw that post, but my log directory does not have a realm-object-server.log file. In fact, I can't find any files that seem related to the realm object server. I previously thought that I launched the incorrect AMI, so I created a new instance, but I am still encountering this porblem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to connect to my server after running these install commands:

```
# Setup Realm's PackageCloud repository
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/realm/realm/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Update the repositories
sudo apt-get update

# Install the Realm Object Server
sudo apt-get install realm-object-server-developer

# Enable and start the service
sudo systemctl enable realm-object-server
sudo systemctl start realm-object-server
```

I had thought that because I was using an AMI provided by realm (ami-fd81f8eb) that the realm object server would already be installed, but it seems that this was not the case.